# facebook post, you can view it only if you share it

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Recently a friend on facebook shared a post, when I wanted to see that post, there came a message that I can see that post only if I share it, so when I shared that post than I saw that post. It was actually a video.

I want to know how to make that type of post which people can see only if they share it.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its something like Splashpost.

Check it out here - https://www.splashpost.com/